# How does solidity online compiler link libraries?

Tags: solidity, remix, library, compiler

Suppose I have this code:

```
import "github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/strings.sol";

contract Contract {
    using strings for *;

    // ...
}
```

For this solidity online compiler generates this byte code:

```
60606040523415600b57fe5b5b60338060196000396000f30060606040525bfe00a165627a7a723058207a17f097139e731ad961366b8214b226041a3cd4427248c94ea39ee29bafface0029
```

Here I don't see any placeholder to add the library address. But when I deploy the byte code it creates a contract successfully.

So how does solidity online compiler find the address of the library?

And how does it know where to deploy the library i.e., mainnet or testnet. I am able to use the same byte code in both mainnet and testnet but the library address may be different in both networks. There are private networks also too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the "strings" library only has functions with `internal` visibility therefore all the functions from the library are copied to the `Contract` contract therefore "strings" library was never deployed and so there isn't any placeholder to add the "strings" library address in the bytecode of `Contract`.

To know why it was copied read this http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#libraries

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ when you're referring to the "solidity online compiler".

If that's the case, here's what happens when you "create" your `Contract`:

1. The `import` generates a library from the github source, compiles it, deploys it, and keeps the address in memory.
2. The compiler compiles your `Contract`, and then links the resulting bytecode to the address of the library's address.
3. The linked bytecode is then deployed to the blockchain.

Hope that clarifies it. I'm a bit out of date on the internals of the browser-solidity project, so hopefully I'm not leading you astray.

Comment: But how does it know where to deploy the contract i.e., mainnet or testnet. I am able to use the same byte code in both mainnet and testnet but the library address may be different in both networks. There are private networks also too.

Comment: By default, browser-solidity deploys to an in-memory JavaScript VM. If you want to deploy to a live blockchain, you need to toggle the "cube" tab, which allows you to specify a Web3 provider endpoint to an Ethereum node. Whatever network that node is connected to is where the contract will be deployed to.

Comment: Exactly. I selected VM for compilation. But I was able to deploy the contract code on mainnet and tested and it worked fine. How did it work when it never got deployed to mainner and testnet?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: The generated bytecode already contains the address of the "strings" library. To deploy the contract on mainnet I need should replace the address right? So that it points to the string library that's on mainnet. But I am able to deploy and run the contract's methods successfully without changing the "strings" library address. How is it possible?

Comment: One more thing I noticed that it happens with only strings library. I created a library of my own than it displayed placeholder for put address. And also this is behaviour of solcjs compiler specifically.